# What tag should I use for a question about "5e: HARDCORE MODE"

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a thing called "[5e: HARDCORE MODE](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/303156/5e-HARDCORE-MODE)" which is basically a set of house rules for the D&D 5th edition. I want to ask a couple of questions about this thing, but I hesitate how to tag these questions. There is no specific [5e-hardcore-mode] tag, and just [dnd-5e] is just wrong, because the question is not about 5e rules, it is about these particular house rules.

Which tag is more preferable? Should I create a new one?

Comment: Highly related: [How to tag 3rd-party/homebrew content that is published?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8714)

Comment: Homebrew content and house rules are different things though. @Someone_Evil

Comment: I would have put this into the 3rd party bucket personally, not sure where it lands on the homebrew to house rule spectrum and not sure how important that is :)

Comment: @enkryptor House Rules and Homebrew aren't really a different thing, they're two sides of the same coin.

Comment: Critical hit and critical failure aren't really different things, they're two sides of the same die @RevenantBacon

Comment: @enkryptor Haha, yes, that's certainly not incorrect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The important bit is to keep the information in the body.

Then, if you are asking a question *about* a topic which we don't have a tag for, sure make one. A specific ruleset counts as such a topic as far as I see.

The tag would then collect questions about that ruleset usefully. Having a tag that collects a narrow topic isn't a cost, and if it's too narrow it'll just get roomba'd (if it doesn't have a description).

As for having a tag for a specific ruleset modification, it's not something that comes up often, but for prior art see the [e6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/e6) tag.