# Am I supposed to be able to add tags to a deleted question?

Tags: bug, tags, deleted-questions

So, today this question was asked: [Can the Warforged Integrated Weapon Trait be Disarmed?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/154969/can-the-warforged-integrated-weapon-trait-be-disarmed)

It is currently deleted (and therefore you need 10K rep to see it).

I just edited the [homebrew](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/homebrew) tag onto it, because it is about homebrew content from [dndguide.com](https://dndguide.com/races/Warforged).

I was fully expecting some kind of message to pop up and tell me that I'm not allowed to edit deleted questions, like if I were to try to up/downvote it, but it didn't the edit went through, as far as I can tell (I have since removed the tag, as I was informed that it wasn't as relevant-a-tag as I first thought).

Regardless of the nature of the edit itself, should I be able to edit tags on deleted questions?

Comment: Side note about [tag:homebrew]: the tag description says "For questions about homebrewing new rules content for an existing system." I don't think we should be using it to mark when the content someone is asking about happens to be created by someone else, only when the question is about *creating* content. Generally, who the creator of the content in the question is, is not relevant. Related: [Is the DMsGuild considered Homebrew and if so, should we always use the homebrew tag in parallel?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7758)

Comment: @Rubiksmoose Fair enough, I assumed that the "homebrew-review" tag was more for new homebrew, and assumed that "homebrew" would cover 3rd party, but that meta question you linked clears that up. I've removed the tag.

Comment: That is more than understandable and you are far from the only one to have thought that I'm sure :) These tags in particular can be rather unintuitive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### You can edit deleted posts other than your self-deleted questions

You can find this clarified in this [general meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/179769/404165):

> 1. No one can edit a locked post.
> 2. The author of a deleted post can edit it unless it is a self-deleted question or locked as noted in #1.
> 3. Folks with full editing rights can edit any deleted post except those restricted by #1 or #2.

You are in case number 3 here, having over 10k rep and not being the author of the question you can edit everything about the question (not just tags)

Note the restriction to editing self-deleted questions is to avoid the abuse described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296102/404165).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this, good to know this is in fact a privilege and not a bug.