# Should we burninate [3rd-party]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

[3rd-party](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party) just seems to be a reincarnation of 3PP, a tag that was [previously burned](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/should-we-get-rid-of-3pp). This tag seems to be used in the exact same way and have the exact same issues as the previously burned tag.

The original was burned for a lot of reasons, but the big one in my mind is that tags are not meant to categorize where the content of the question comes from, but what the content of the question actually is in a way that makes it easy for people to browse topics of interest to them.

Unless there is some shift and [3rd-party](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/3rd-party) is suddenly a useful concept for us, I think the tag should be burned.

Comment: I could see it being meaningful if a system truly did have licensing mechanics to create content the way video game consoles do, but if any specific system did/does that then I think a separate tag specifically for [system-3rd-party] would be better. As you say, the current form of [3rd-party] just seems to be [3pp] with a slightly more comprehensible name.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Yeah, in which case that licensing mechanic should itself be the topic, since they're not usefully grouped. (See [[tag:ogl]] for example.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With very much the [same reasons](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7170/30306) as had been in the 3PP case and most notably

> but one cannot be an expert on "third party publishers". – doppelgreener♦

So I vote to unleash the Imperial Inquisition on this one:

> Burn the Heretic, Kill the Mutant, Purge the Unclean