# Should we have tags for Ultramodern 5e and Esper Genesis?

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e

In this question:
[Should I allow a PC's spells to affect a very large space vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/156818/should-i-allow-a-pcs-spells-to-affect-a-very-large-vehicle)
They ask about balance and how it relates to some mechanics from the 5th Edition D&D mod (addon?) [Ultramodern 5e](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/190188/Ultramodern5-5th-Edition), and actually includes additional rules from [Esper Genesis](https://espergenesis.alligatoralleyentertainment.com/) (a 3rd party source for space combat).

Is this all properly contained under the 5e tag for the question, or should we also include other tags like [ultramodern-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ultramodern-5e) and [esper-genesis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esper-genesis)?

Or maybe even just [dnd-5e-3rdparty](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e-3rdparty) (exact verbiage up for debate) to cover everything?

Comment: For the record, I originally added a ultramodern-5e tag to it, but it was lost in simultanous edits.

Comment: [3pp](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7169) and [3rd-party](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8239) have both been burninated in the past. I suspect a [dnd-5e-3rdparty] would not pass the test of fire either.

Answer (score 14):

Sure, add the tags. Tags are free and useful.

- If we have three questions about Ultramodern, that’s two more than are needed to justify that tag.
- We have plenty of tags that started out their existence on just one question, and never gained more than a handful. There’s no harm in creating [esper-genesis](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esper-genesis), and it might or might not grow, like any new tag.

Comment: +1. This makes more sense than what I had suggested.

Comment: As SSD suggested, this is fine. I've now created the [ultramodern5] tag (as it's named), with [ultramodern-5e] as a synonym of it.

Comment: As a follow-up question, should this new tag be used _instead of_ [dnd-5e] or _as well as_? If the latter, must [dnd-5e] _always_ accompany [ultramodern5] now (like how the [[tolkiens-legendarium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tolkiens-legendarium)] tag on scifi.se _must always_ accompany any [[the-lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-lord-of-the-rings)], [[the-hobbit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-hobbit)], [[the-silmarillion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-silmarillion)], etc. tags)?

Comment: @NathanS: Since it's a hack of D&D 5e, I think it's generally appropriate to use both tags (as is done with [dnd-5e] alongside [adventures-in-middle-earth]). Might be good to ask it as its own question, though, once this one has shaken itself out.

Comment: @V2Blast I don't think this needs its own question, your answer makes sense to me. I think of it as comparable to the [unearthed-arcana] tag, or one of the 5e adventure tags (such as [out-of-the-abyss]); technically they are about 5e (the tag information confirms such), so technically they could be used on their own without the [dnd-5e] tag, but in practice we do combine those with the [dnd-5e] tag, so it makes sense to me that we should for this new [ultramodern5] tag also.